# How can i create a carousel slide with div column-9 and another sub-content on div column-3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a carousel slide on div class column 9 and also create a banner on the div class column 3 on same row. I want to achieve having a carousel slide on the div class-col-9 and also have banners on div class-col-3 on same row with the carousel. I'm having issues having my carousel slides on div class col 9 and banners on div class col-3 on same column, instead, my banners in div class col-3 is beneath the carousel which is not supposed to be so. 
I'm doing it for a client who said he wants a blog very similar to naijaloaded.com.ng

I have tried trying to place my carousel slide which I also added a div class col-9 to be in same column with my banners ads which I gave a div class col-3 but instead, the banners ads started another row instead to being same column with the carousel slide

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I'm not sure if i can accurately tell you what you can do, but here's what I got from your question:

1. You have a row that is split into 2/3 for a carousel, and 1/3 for a banner.
2. Your 2/3 column is pushing your 1/3 column down, but you want them to show up side by side.

One way I can suggest doing this is by using the css property `float: left` on both of the columns, and see if that works.

This is most likely happening because rows and columns by default have a browser-rendered margin around them. If you have a border around your columns, that will also offset their position so that they don't show up next to each other, in which case you're better off using `display: grid` or setting up borders like this:

```html
.2/3 column {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}

.1/3 column {
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  margin-left: -2px
}
```

I hope this helps!